# Passing vectors from C++ to Python using pybind11

Tags: python, c++

I'm trying to develop an application where I need to pass vector data from c++ to an embedded python interpreter. I'm using pybind11.
My goal is to have the c++ vector modified by python.

for example:

```cpp
namespace py = pybind11;

int main()
{

    py::scoped_interpreter guard{}; // start the interpreter and keep it alive
    py::object main = py::module::import("__main__");
    py::object globals = main.attr("__dict__");



    double* myVect = new double[100];
    memset(myVect, 0, sizeof(double) * 100);
    myVect[0] = 1.0;
    myVect[99] = 2.0;
    size_t size = 100;
    py::array pyVect((size_t)100, myVect);
    globals["myArray"] = pyVect;
    std::cout << myVect[0] << "    ---   " << myVect[99] << std::endl;
    py::exec("print(myArray)");
    py::exec("myArray = myArray[::-1]");
    py::exec("print(myArray)");
    std::cout << myVect[0] << "    ---   " << myVect[99] << std::endl;
    delete[] myVect;

}
```

the array in python is reversed, but not the c++ vector. This is because the assignment to the python makes the copy of the vector.
Is it possible to pass directly the pointer in order to modify the c++ vector directly from python?

Comment: I don't see a vector in here. Do you mean array?

Comment: yes, i am sorry i mean an array